# Create model with new parent model parent_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a photos form inside the posts/_form.html.haml

Looks like this:

```
.row
  .large-9.large-centered.columns
    = simple_nested_form_for @post do |f|
      = f.input :title, label: "Title"
      = f.input :body, label: "Body", input_html: { rows: 15}
      /= link_to_add_fields "Add image", f, :photos
      = f.submit "Mentés", class: "button"

- if user_signed_in?
  = simple_form_for @post.photos.new do |f|
    %h3
      Image upload
      %i.fi-upload
    = f.input :image, input_html: { multiple: true, name: "photo[image]"}, label: false
    = f.input :post_id, val: @post.id, as: :hidden
```

On an edit action, all photos are saved with the correct post_id.
But on a create action when Post.new gets created, it doesn't have an id before, so the photos don't get the post_id.

Somehow this could be fixed? Maybe deleting this line:

```
= f.input :post_id, val: @post.id, as: :hidden
```

and change the controller to pass the id.

Posts controller create action:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this

In new method use this line

```
  @post = Post.new
  @post.photos.build
```

Suppose if you want new photo in edit mode means
In edit method use this

```
  @post.photos.build
```

In post model you have to use

```
 has_may :photos
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

In form update the code as below

```
.row
  .large-9.large-centered.columns
    = simple_nested_form_for @post do |f|
      = f.input :title, label: "Title"
      = f.input :body, label: "Body", input_html: { rows: 15}
      /= link_to_add_fields "Add image", f, :photos

      - if user_signed_in?
        = f.fields_for :photos do |photo|
          %h3
            Image upload
            %i.fi-upload
          = photo.input :image, input_html: { multiple: true}, label: false

      = f.submit "Mentés", class: "button"
```

I hope this will helps.